# Styling an angular directive on ng-click with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives that should both use isolate scopes, `<outer-box>` and `<flag>`. When I click on the `<flag>` directive, I want to change the background color of the other directive. Before importing my code into JSFiddle, I also had it working so that by default, a placeholder image appears in the flag directive, but once you click on that image, the country flag appears instead.

Can someone help with the styling a separate directive on ng-click?

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/nLduw6xw/
(My countries data isn't working in JSFiddle for some reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with requiring one directive from another.
In this example you can require `outer-box` to be a parent of `flag`.
With this you have the access to required directive controller ( 4th parameter in `link` function), so you can call a method to set class on element.

Working JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2atnxhgy/

Comment: Thanks a million! :)